# ldentifying observations on the edges in heteroscedastic data

Tags: conditional-probability, standard-deviation, outliers, heteroscedasticity

Consider bivariate data consisting of correlated variables (r ~ 0.9). It is known how both the variables are calculated. Each observation is identically distributed but **non independent**. Also, the dataset is fairly skewed in nature.

Given this information, i'm interested in isolating observations that exhibit high deviation from the conditional mean of the dependent variable *given* the value of the independent variable. As most of the statistical assumptions fail in this case (non independence, skewness), what would be a good way of going about doing this?

Here is a glimpse of the data:

```
 Independent    Dependent
 34903602883    8.39206E+13
 34455688425    6.36408E+12
 34030939061    7.84165E+13
 29842572343    3.26644E+13
 29229730881    5.33052E+13
 23079743414    2.2329E+13
 1158.2         133519.05
 1020.63        5607390.48
 1006.88        0
 970.11         332761.38
 950.23         3661218.52
```

Some plots of non transformed and log-transformed data respectively:
[image: plot 50]
[image: log plot]

Assume conditional variance varies as some function of the independent variable. How do I find observations in my data sample nearest to the edges, perhaps a score based on the distance from those edges?

Conditional mean and variance are respectively the mean and variance of the probability distribution of dependent variable (y-axis) given a value of the independent variable.

UPDATE: Here is my initial approach, thanks to the comments:

1. Model conditional mean using nonparametric methods (for instance, a local linear estimator) on the log-transformed data.
2. Calculate squared residuals from the conditional mean {e(i) = Y(i) - m(X(i))}
3. Model conditional variance of the squared residuals, again using some nonparametric method.
4. Studentize the residuals obtained from (2) using the conditional variance model so obtained.

Again, I would like to stress that the presence of heteroscedasticity and non-independence renders this problem as not-so-trivial, which had me resort to transformations (though heteroscedasticity still prevails), not to mention this approach is seemingly quite ad-hoc.

Also, the application of non-parametric methods should require relatively more data (in my case there are ~800 observations).

Here is a plot of studentized residuals vs. conditional means in the logs:
[image]

Although these results look ok, i'm still somewhat skeptical about my exercise. Is there some way to reinforce this? Or, perhaps use more robust methods?

Comment: (1) It is not in the least clear that there are any boundaries in the first plot except for the obvious positivity constraints. (2) If you construct a model for the conditional distribution--for instance, if you suppose the residuals of the logs are iid or if you suppose the variances of the residuals are a linear function of the independent variable--then *the model* identifies the observation with greatest conditional variance (the *rightmost* one in both your examples). Do not confuse that with observations near these (non-existent) boundaries!

Comment: @whuber maybe it is not clear within this plot. Let me post one with more observations. But consider the second plot, the upper boundary is linear in the Logs. I know the methodology with which the dependent variable is computed. Please assume that (it may not be linear) for the first one.

Comment: OK, if you *know* there is an upper boundary, that's fine--but it doesn't seem highly relevant to your question about conditional variance. Your concept of identifying a "conditional variance" within *individual values* seems misguided to me, perhaps because I might have a different understanding of this term than you intended. Could you please edit your question to clarify what this value is supposed to mean?

Comment: Done. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but I am still baffled: when conditional variance is a function of the independent variable, as you write, then *by definition* the points where that variance are greatest are found by inspecting the independent [horizontal] variable and *have nothing whatsoever to do with how close to a [vertical] boundary the point might be.*

Comment: Hmm. I get what you are trying to say. Allow me to put it another way. Forget about any boundaries, I want to calculate deviation of the dependent variable in my sample from the expected value of its conditional distribution given a value for the independent variable. Doing so would help isolate observations (applying a threshold) nearest to the plot edges.

Comment: Thank you: that's a very different question from the one you were originally asking!  You are looking for *studentized residuals*.  This will still require an explicit model of the conditional variance.

Comment: @whuber: Thank you for clarifying. So here is what I have done as an initial ad-hoc approach: 1. Model the expected values of the conditional means using a local linear estimator on the logs and optimal BW selection based on cross validation of least squares. 2. Calculate squared deviation from the conditional means so obtained. 3. Model the variance again as a second step using another local linear estimator to estimate conditional expected values of variance. 4. Calculate deviation/expected conditional variance for each point to obtain the final rank score. I wonder if something is missing.

Comment: If you would edit your question to incorporate that latest comment it might attract some more attention and perhaps get a focused, appropriate answer.